# develop vtk in codeblocks

Tags: c++, vtk

I installed vtk in debian6.0.6 successfully, I build a static lib. I run the examples and everything is ok.

But I want to develop in codeblocks. So I created a project in codeblocks, copy the code "cone.cxx" into my project, I set the include path and linkers. But there are compile errors like "undefined reference to...", I guess that is because it can not find the interfaces in the static lib.

I guess I need some #defines before compile my project. I can see the pre_defines in visual studio2008, but I can not get it in codeblocks because the codeblocks project use its makefile defaultly. Can I get a solution if I don't want to write a makefile?

Comment: Undefined reference to... is a linker error. Did you add `-lvtk_lib_name` to the linker options (or rather just `vtk_lib_name` to the "Link libraries" section)?

Comment: thank you very much for your adcive.I add all the link libs needed. I guess I need to add some pre_defines to the IDE, but I don't know how to get them.I can get the pre_defines in vs2008, but I don't know how to get them in codeblocks because codeblocks actually use makefile while compiling examples. Is there any advice?thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how predefined variables would solve a linking issue.

Comment: thank you. I solve my problem just now. I use cmake to generate a makefile and it works. I can generate a project for vtk in vs but I think setting the environment in codeblocks in linux for vtk is not easy.